# Dim myArray as data type of another array

Tags: vba

If I have an array `array2()` of a given type, say for example `Single`, or `String`, or any other type.

How do I define `array2()` such that it has the same data type as `array1()`?

something like this:

```
Dim array2() As TypeName(array1())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaring everything as variant can introduce a fairly significant performance hit in some situations.  you could always try the DataTypeofArray function at this site:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Answer (score 2):

How about just `Dim array2()`? That leaves it as type variant.

Comment: Ok, then my question is, how badly will the performance suffer or what will be the effect if I convert all single, integer and double arrays in my program to variants?